# Is there a way to "flatten" a Chessboard pattern apart from lense correction?

Tags: opencv, camera-calibration, distortion

I checked the tutorials [here](https://medium.com/analytics-vidhya/camera-calibration-with-opencv-f324679c6eb7) and [here](https://medium.com/hackernoon/how-to-unwrap-wine-labels-programmatically-31c8c62b30ce), and I'm looking for something similar.

So far, I managed to solve lense distortion using a Chessboard pattern, just as below (this is an average result example, i made it quickly just for this question, but you get the point):

[Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Gj0c.png)

[To this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/udLtR.png)

The "barrel" distortion due to the cyllindrical surface from which the chessboard is in is partially fixed. But, more than the lense/distortion correction, I wanted the camera_matrix to "flatten" the chessboard pattern (i.e., to make all squares same size), similarly as the unwrap wine label similarly as used in [Nepherhotep/unwrap_labels](https://github.com/Nepherhotep/unwrap_labels), but using the Chessboard rather than the markers instead.

Is there anything similar?

Comment: I didn't get it, is the chessboard on a cylindrical surface and you want to flatten it? And you tried to do that by distortion correction?

Comment: @Micka Exactly. The distortion correction does not make all square sizes equal, it only makes all curved lines straight.

Comment: So have you tried already using the chessboard points as label markers in the unwrap_labels example ? You do get the point positions from the first example, you can directly input them in the unwrap_label for the same image or am I not understanding something ?

Comment: First you should make sure that your camera lens actually is distortion corrected (e.g. with a planar chessboard object) and then you will need the geometric transformation/warping from cylindrical scene to planar scene. Do you know the 3D points of your rolled chessboard? Easiest might be to know/compute the 2D texture coordinates of the chessboard on your 3D cylinder.